# Recovering HDD partition table using Testdisk

Tags: partitioning, multi-boot, partition-recovery, testdisk

I have a total of 4 operating systems installed on my notebook. I use a WD Blue 1TB 2.5" internal HDD. The installed OSes are Win XP, Win 7, Win 8 and Ubuntu.

Of these, Windows XP only boots when I change my HDD operation mode from AHCI to IDE because I couldn't find the right SATA driver for it during installation.

A few days ago, due to a power outage and failed notebook batteries, my computer shut down improperly. At the time, it was connected to a 2TB WD external HDD. Since then, my computer wouldn't boot and spit out the following error code :

```
0x0000225 ("Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause")
```

I read on a forum somewhere that other people have also experienced the same problem when they've left an external USB HDD connected to the computer while it shut down.

I tried all the regular methods (startup repair, bcdboot, bcdedit, etc.) but nothing worked so I booted from a GParted Live CD and ran testdisk, read the instructions and after quite a bit of trial and error, got Windows 8 to boot again.

After booting to Win 8, I was missing several partitions so I ran testdisk again, performed a Deeper Search for partitions and this is what I got:

```
TestDisk 6.14, Data Recovery Utility, July 2013
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org

Disk /dev/sda - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
>  HPFS - NTFS              0  32 33  1529 232 47   24576000 [PQSERVICE]
   HPFS - NTFS              0  32 40  1529 232 47   24575993
   HPFS - NTFS           1529 232 47  3059 177 54   24575993
   HPFS - NTFS           1529 232 48  1542 168 34     204800 [SYSTEM RESERVED]
   HPFS - NTFS           1529 232 55  1542 168 34     204793
   HPFS - NTFS           1530  64 21  1542 254 63     204793
   HPFS - NTFS           1542 168 27  1555 104  6     204793
   HPFS - NTFS           1542 168 34  1555 104 13     204793
   HPFS - NTFS           1542 168 42 10680 147 27  146800633
   HPFS - NTFS          10680 147 28 38678 245 31  449794048 [Miscellaneous]
   HPFS - NTFS          10680 157  4 38678 254 63  449794041
   HPFS - NTFS          20176 216  9 33230 226 20  209713152 [RootWin7]
   HPFS - NTFS          20176 216 16 33230 226 20  209713145
   HPFS - NTFS          20176 216 16 41048 185 33  335306745
   HPFS - NTFS          41048 218  3 54102 228 14  209713152 [RootWin8]
   HPFS - NTFS          41048 218 10 54102 228 14  209713145
   HPFS - NTFS          41048 218 10 62864 188 44  350472185
   HPFS - NTFS          41048 244 59 54102 254 63  209713145
   HPFS - NTFS          62864 221 14 89313 212 51  424902656 [Music and Other St
   HPFS - NTFS          62864 221 21 89313 212 51  424902649
   HPFS - NTFS          62865   8 33 89313 254 63  424902649
   HPFS - NTFS          87764 171 31 115763  14 27  449794041
   HPFS - NTFS          89313 245 21 115762 236 58  424902656 [Movies and TV Sho
   HPFS - NTFS          89313 245 28 115762 236 58  424902649
   Linux                100907  14 36 102404  52 48   24051712
   Linux                100914 115  2 102411 153 14   24051712
   HPFS - NTFS          115763  14 28 119679  45 46   62912512 [Stuff]
   HPFS - NTFS          115763  14 35 119679  45 46   62912505
   HPFS - NTFS          115763 223 52 119679 254 63   62912505
Structure: Ok.  Use Up/Down Arrow keys to select partition.
Use Left/Right Arrow keys to CHANGE partition characteristics:
*=Primary bootable  P=Primary  L=Logical  E=Extended  D=Deleted
Keys A: add partition, L: load backup, T: change type, P: list files,
     Enter: to continue
```

I can't see the Windows XP partiton in the list (probably because my HDD is currently set to AHCI mode?)

All the partitions without a label are corrupt but the partitions with labels are fine and I can access their files using the "P: list files" option of Testdisk.

Currently, the SYSTEM RESERVED partition is set as primary bootable and I have made no changes to the partition table since booting into Windows 8 for fear of screwing something up.

I ran Easy BCD and here's what I got:

```
There are a total of 4 entries listed in the bootloader.

Default: Windows 7
Timeout: 30 seconds
EasyBCD Boot Device: C:\

Entry #1
Name: Earlier Version of Windows
BCD ID: {ntldr}
Device: \Device\HarddiskVolume1
Bootloader Path: \ntldr

Entry #2
Name: Windows 8
BCD ID: {current}
Drive: C:\
Bootloader Path: \Windows\system32\winload.exe

Entry #3
Name: Windows 7
BCD ID: {default}
Device: unknown
Bootloader Path: \Windows\system32\winload.exe

Entry #4
Name: Ubuntu
BCD ID: {04e5904e-05ff-11e2-a3bd-9cf748453e70}
Device: unknown
Bootloader Path: \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr
```

How can I recover all my partitions and get all the OSes booting again?

Could you help me set the correct attribute (primary, logical, primary bootable, etc.) to each of the partions that Testdisk recovers?

Also, here's a link to the complete Testdisk Log after the Deeper Scan stage: https://db.tt/LPmoGWn0